# Ms Dynamics Integration with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics, adal

I am Using ADAL libs for java to connect **MS Dynamics CRM** in my backend application. I registered my trial version of CRM Azure Active Direstory and I got clientID and clientsecret from there. So now I can able to connect with my crm.

But my question is If I have multiple CRM Account how should I do this.Is there any api to register the CRM in azure active directory or is there any API to do that using the CRM crendials?

Can anyone please explain me.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the MS Dynamics CRM only support Authorization code grant flow(OAuth).

If you were developing an web app, it should works well for your scenario. Since every user could sign-in the web app and than the web app can delegate the user to integrate with MSDynamics.

More detail authentication with Microsoft Dynamics 365, you can refer the document below:

[Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx)

Comment: so I must register my every crm account in the active directory manually would it be possible to get the access token by using the  crm crendials alone?

Comment: No, you only need to register the app. There is no need to register the CRM account. More detail register the app, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622431.aspx).  Based on my understanding,  both **Resource Owner password credentials flow** and **OAuthrization code grant flow** are delegate the user's permission. It should able to support the **Resource Owner password credentials flow**, you can refer the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) here to verify it.